# CSS rotate is not work @media query does not change back after rotating

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have been spending a week to solve the issue on a media query but I still not able to solve this issue.  The image is still not able to rotate when it shift to the 1028 pixel.

I have a image at the on the red background of my web site. I want the image to change in response to a screen with no rotate when is reach to 1028px. I understand this is the best way to using by @media query as per the source below and rotate with 0.  I think I am in right way to do, but the problem is the image is not effect for what I input. I am sure that @media query suppose to applies and the image suppose could rotate. When minimize the screen to be 1028 px, the image just dropped over from the top container to the second and third container.  Which I think this is super ridiculous!

I hope you guys could give me some support, and I have taken a screen capture to show this working:

[image: image is not showing rotate by zero]

[image: Look at this]

```css
/* title-image */
.title-image{
  width:60%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(25deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotate(25deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate (25deg);
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;

}

@media (max-width: 1028px){
  .title-image:{
    position: static;
    transform: rotate(0);

      }
}
```

Comment: You have a colon in your CSS after `.title-image:` that’s causing your style to not be applied. Delete the colon and the style will be applied when the display is under 1028px wide.

Comment: One other note – for Bootstrap, usually designs start with the title-image being set to width 60% (mobile first), and then add the position absolute and rotation stuff at a **min**-width of 1029px.

Comment: thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tite-image {
    position: static;
     transform: rotate(0);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same course as you. full stack web course on udemy right?

I had the same problem the Phone just didnt want to rotate back for me so instead i kept the rotation at 0 until the screen size went above 1028px

```
   .iphonedog
    {
      width: 300px;
      margin-left: 100px;
      
      position: relative;
      top: 10%;
      left: 50px;
    
    }
@media (min-width: 1028px)
{
  .iphonedog
  {
    position: static;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    
  }
  
}
```

This fixed it for me.